# CUDA find sum of elements of the array

Tags: arrays, cuda

hello I want to find the sum of array elements using CUDA.

```
__global__ void countZeros(int *d_A, int * B)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    B[0] = B[0]+d_A[index];
}
```

so in the end, B[0] supposed to contain the sum of all elements. but I noticed that B[0] equals to zero every time. so in the end it contains only last element.
why B[0] becomes zero every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the threads are writing to `B[0]`, and some may be attempting to write simultaneously.  This line of code:

```
B[0] = B[0]+d_A[index];
```

requires a read and a write of `B[0]`.  If multiple threads are doing this at the same time, you will get strange results.

You can make a simple fix by doing this:

```
atomicAdd(B, d_A[index]);
```

and you should get sensible results (assuming you have no errors elsewhere in your code, that you haven't shown.)  Be sure to initialize `B[0]` to some known value before calling this kernel.

If you want to do this efficiently, however, you should study the cuda [reduction sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) or just use [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html).

And be sure to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code.

So, if you still can't get sensible results, *please* instrument your code with proper cuda error checking before asking "I made this change but it still doesn't work, why?"  I can't tell you why, because this is the only snippet of code that you've shown.

Comment: thanks but atomicAdd is undefined. I have suspecion that it's not possible to do it my way. It seems like one var can be chaned only one time.

Comment: To use `atomicAdd`, you will need to compile your code with an architecture switch for a GPU that is cc1.1 or higher.  So for example if you have a cc2.0 GPU, add `-arch=sm_20` to your compile command line.  If you do actually have a cc1.0 GPU, then this won't work, but the reduction sample code can still be made to work.

Comment: seems like too much to worry about. Maybe it could be done by using shared memory?

Comment: nvcc -o -arch=sm_20 A A.cu doesn't compile

Comment: That is because you put the arch parameter in between the -o switch and the argument (A) to the -o switch.  Try this instead:  `nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o A A.cu`